# Why does my 2-month-old consistently fuss at nightfall?

Tags: behavior, newborn, crying, night-time

My 2-month-old daughter consistently fusses or screams around sundown/nightfall regardless of the sky being overcast, the lights in the house being on, or apparently any other factor.

Is this common, and is there any known reason it happens?

Comment: Both of our girls did that as well.  I heard that it was one of their ways of getting rid of some extra energy.

Answer (score 10):

Very common - it's generally called the witching hour, and each of our kids needed something different to sooth them through it.

One responded well to walking up and down the street with me singing to her.

I know some need to face in, others need to face out.

Comment: **"witching hour"** could possibly be it. We generally found that being in-door and holding them close during sunset really helps. What ever this might be it cant harm holding or being close to them to support them.

Answer (score 3):

See http://www.purplecrying.info. In short, it's a phase all children go through, some more severely than others, but the crying is a natural part of a baby's development. It helps baby's lungs develop, helps the baby bond with its parents (or whomever shows up when the crying starts), and in trying to soothe your baby you'll introduce visual, aural and tactile stimulation that helps your baby's brain develop.